# Word for a person who wants to have problems to gain attention or sympathy

Tags: single-word-requests, personality

Is there a word for a disease or personality type where a person wants to have problems to gain attention or sympathy. I came across something closer called '[Munchausen Syndrome](https://www.webmd.com/mental-health/munchausen-syndrome)'. But it is about a person who 'pretends' to have problems, not actually wants to have problems.

Edit: It is not a duplicate of *[Is there a word for someone who somewhat delights in their illnesses/medications?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/24016/is-there-a-word-for-someone-who-somewhat-delights-in-their-illnesses-medications)*, because the problems do not necessarily relate to a medical condition. They can be of a financial situation or relationship issues.

Answer (score 3):

That's called *Martyr complex* in psychology.

> In psychology a person who has a *martyr complex*, sometimes associated with the term *victim complex*, desires the feeling of being a martyr for their own sake, seeking out suffering or persecution because it either feeds a psychical need or a desire to avoid responsibility. [[**Wikipedia**]](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martyr_complex)

Or try *self-pity*.

> Self-pity is an emotion "directed towards others with the goal of attracting attention, empathy, or help" and one in which the subject feels sorry for (feels pity for) themselves. [[**Wikipedia**]](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-pity)

That kind of person is called *self-pitying* person.

Comment: 'Martyr Complex' is a closer word but self-pity is the match for the description. Is there any medical name for 'self-pity'?

Comment: @srand9, I knew a medical term for that.... will have to rack my brain...

Comment: Munchausen syndrome still applies. Sometimes people with Munchausen syndrome go out of their way to injure themselves because they want attention so badly.  But it's *Personality Disorder; could be Emotionally Unstable Personality Disorder.*

Comment: Munchausen syndrome is actually about a person who 'pretends'. And EUPD or BPD doesn't seem to be correct. I'm actually observing a person who is having the symptoms as in my question. Like, the person is perfectly normal and intelligent in all the situations. But the person is attention-seeking to the level they intentionally take the problems onto them. For example, the mentioned person has an own house, but they want to move to a rented house just to make others think that they are poor and no one is helping them. This is an example and there could be other different situations.

Comment: @srand9, I will ask my friends and will let you know if I find anything.

Comment: @srand9, [**Histrionic:**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/histrionic) (of behavior) showing a lot of emotion in order to persuade others or attract attention. AND [**Histrionic personality disorder**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histrionic_personality_disorder). I don't think there is a single word for that.

Answer (score 1):

**Sadfishing**.

> A behavioural trend where people make exaggerated claims about their emotional problems to generate sympathy.

Comment: What's the source of this definition?

Comment: It's from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sadfishing) but you should cite the source of quotations.

Comment: If you add the reference (link and attribution) you're more likely to attract upvotes, and rep points bring important privileges (and are some measure of credibility). A little more of the article would also be useful; this will be a novel term to many.

Answer (score 0):

If the problems are health related, there is the term "hypochondriac".

Also, "attention seeking behavior" is in established use.

Comment: Hypochondriac is when a person believes that he has a problem. Also, attention seeking behaviour can be by pretending to have a problem. My request is very specific that the person wants to have problems.

Comment: That's quite specific, I can't think of a term like that.

Answer (score -1):

The person in question is affected by “[Borderline personality disorder](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borderline_personality_disorder)“

> Borderline personality disorder (BPD), also known as emotionally unstable personality disorder (EUPD), is a mental illness characterized by a long-term pattern of unstable relationships, distorted sense of self, and strong emotional reactions. ***Individuals often engage in self-harm and other dangerous behavior.***

(Wikipedia)

Comment: They *might* be affected, but not all will have BPD.